# Problem in Adobe Illustrator while dealing with images

Tags: adobe-illustrator

After installing Adobe Illustrator CC 2017 through Adobe Creative Cloud I am experiencing the problem in placing images into the artboard in AI CC 2017.

-> ctrl + shift + P does not work.

-> dragging and dropping does not work from File explorer as well as from my library synced with the creative cloud.

I am running Windows 8.1 64-bit and I am sure the installation part was perfect.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Try trashing/resetting your preferences. It should clear out the issue. If not it could be a plug-in not playing nicely. I am not sure how to reset your preferences on PC, hopefully someone else can supply that info.